# How to write a hidden structure's attributes generically? (a design/implementation for C++)

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have following template.

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    .............
private:
   T _data;
}
```

When I use it, T is always a structure (data only). For example,

```
struct ST1{
    int a;
    int b;
};
struct ST2{
    int a1;
    int b1;
    int c1;
}
```

For a particular instance of MyClass, e.g., `MyClass<struct ST1> myinstance`, I would like to access `myinstance.data.a` or `myinstance.data.b`. One generic way I can think of is to define methods in MyClass like

```
void MyClass::write(T const &){ _data = T;}
T    MyClass::read(){return _data;}
```

But the problem is that for every read and write, I need to create an structure instance, even though I only access a small portion of the `_data`.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want `_data` to be hidden and an implementation detail, or do you want the users of `MyClass` to access it? In the latter case, just make it public. It feels like you're creating the problem you're having.

Comment: a getter method that return the reference to `_data` would do, although it break encapsulation, but so are your write and read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
const T& MyClass::GetData() const { return _data; }
T& MyClass::GetData() { return _data; }
```

Then you can just do...

```
myClass.GetData().a = 17;
```

You could also just make `_data` public.

Comment: Butter than my. It's simple. Thanks

Comment: I'd be against this pattern, because if you are doing this, why not just expose `_data` directly?  The binary layout of `_data` is already exposed by the above method, and you cannot do any post processing on `_data` after the user changes it...

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is think about making `_data` public.  If it is just data, and it isn't active, and having its binary layout exposed isn't a problem, this works.

If you want to be able to "bookend" access to `_data` (say, with mutexes, or getting/setting some information remotely), and you have access to C++11 lambdas, this pattern can be useful:

```
template<typename Lambda>
auto Data( Lambda&& closure )->decltype( closure(_data) ) {
  // do pre-processing
  auto retval = closure(_data);
  // do post-processing
  return retval;
}
template<typename Lambda>
auto Data( Lambda&& closure ) const->decltype( closure(_data) ) {
  // do pre-processing
  auto retval = closure(_data);
  // do post-processing
  return retval;
}
```

which you'd use like this:

```
int main() {
  MyClass<Foo> instance;
  int x = instance.Data( [&]( Foo const& foo ) {
    return foo.x;
  });
  instance.Data( [&]( Foo& foo ) {
    foo.y = 3;
  });
}
```

which lets you manipulate your data "inside" wrapping code for the `MyClass`.

This is a bit awkward until C++14 `auto` lambdas show up, because you have to repeat the type of `Foo`.

A benefit to this style is that `MyClass` doesn't even have to store an instance of `Foo`!  It could generate the `Foo` on demand, then read back from what the user changed.